# ReactJS - JSON.parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string like so: `"{'store':'AAAAAA', 'online':'BBBBB'}"`

and I am trying to convert this to an object and I have tried this:

```
let code = "{'store':'AAAAAA', 'online':'BBBBB'}"

let actualCode = JSON.parse(code);
```

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it? So I can use like to so:

```
actualCode.store

//Result AAAAAA
```

Thanks,

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Properties and values need to use `"`.

Answer (score 2):

In JSON you have to use double quotations to indicate items:

```js
let code = '{"store":"AAAAAA", "online":"BBBBB"}'
let actualCode = JSON.parse(code);
console.log(actualCode.store);
```